# Why is the food we consume right from birth not immunogenic to elicit an immune response?

Tags: human-biology, immunology, immune-system

Excluding the hypersensitive reactions which are individual specific, how is  food we consume considered safe by the immune system?

Answer (score 2):

Actually for few food items we do develop some sort of immunity. Let me give an example—

Suppose in an individual's RBC membrane, there's a specific ABO antigen (let's say the subject has "A" blood group).
Now in that individual, how do you think anti B antibodies will be formed?

It will essentially be due to some food intake and subsequent exposure to 'B Antigen'. Hence we usually tend to say that 'blood group—A' has anti-B antibody.

This article might be helpful (See the section: Basic Biochemistry$>$ABO Phenotype--4th paragraph)

> https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK2267/

Comment: Can you link to some literature that shows we are exposed to ABO antigens through food?

Comment: Yes, sure. I have added  an article.

Comment: That's interesting, I never knew that before. Or, if I was taught it once I forgot :)